# Mysql is it possible to do the following?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have a mysql query, that does the following,

```
SELECT * FROM categoryTable 
LEFT JOIN userMenuTable 
ON userMenuTable.categoryId = categoryTable.categoryId
```

this returns only results that match this condition

```
ON userMenuTable.categoryId = categoryTable.categoryId
```

I was hoping it would be possible to pull all the results and also the ones from the JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a left outer join, as in your example, will contain all records of the "left" `categoryTable`, even if the join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" `userMenuTable`.

On the other hand, a right outer join resembles a left outer join, except with the treatment of the tables reversed. Every row from the "right" `userMenuTable` will appear in the result-set at least once.

As [a1ex07 suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253377/mysql-is-it-possible-to-do-the-following/2253431#2253431), it may look like you need a [full outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join), which in MySQL can be emulated with a `UNION` between a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need FULL JOIN (mysql doesn't have that syntax, but you can achieve desired result by UNION + LEFT + RIGHT JOIN)

```
SELECT * FROM categoryTable 
LEFT JOIN userMenuTable 
ON userMenuTable.categoryId = categoryTable.categoryId
UNION
SELECT * FROM categoryTable 
RIGHT JOIN userMenuTable 
ON userMenuTable.categoryId = categoryTable.categoryId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that perhaps what you're looking for is a full outer join.  MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN, but you can get the equivalent using LEFT and RIGHT JOINS:

```
SELECT * FROM categoryTable LEFT JOIN userMenuTable
  ON categoryTable.categoryId = userMenuTable.categoryId
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM categoryTable RIGHT JOIN userMenuTable
  ON categoryTable.categoryId = userMenuTable.categoryId
WHERE categoryTable.categoryId IS NULL;
```

Share and enjoy.